# Extracting text between backslashes in webload (or other similar applications?)

Tags: webloadui

In Webload, there is a function extractValue("start","end", source, 1) that basically just extracts any values between a specified start and end point. So for example if you have abcdefg and you want to extract cde you could do extractValue("b","f", source, 1) etc. However, the issue i am having is because webload seems to use backslashes as a marker for quotations, so for example if you had something like 
ab"cde"fg you would need to use something like extractValue("b\"","\"f", source, 1) if you only wanted to extract cef.

Now my issue is I have a string like abcde\ and I want to extract only cde, I try something like 
extractValue("ab","\", source, 1), however when doing this webload assumes I am not ending my string since it interprets the second quotation in "\" as part of the string.

Does anyone know how exactly I should deal with this if I want \ to be interpreted as part of a string and not as the indicator for the quotation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try using two backslashes like extractValue("ab","\\", source, 1), this is another example for using escape character using backslash in extractValue function

myTitle = extractValue( "<\title>", "</title>",
MyFrame.document.wlSource)  backslash title is the title tag..i dont know why it is not getting displayed in the answer.